# How to hide/unregister the Accounts and Social accounts created by django-allauth from django admin?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-admin, django-allauth

I am beginner to django and i wanted to try google authentication and when i followed the steps from [here](https://whizzoe.medium.com/in-5-mins-set-up-google-login-to-sign-up-users-on-django-e71d5c38f5d5) i am able to sucessfully add a google login button but it also showing the ACCOUNTS and Social Accounts in django admin. How can i hide them ? I tried unregistering them but it always giving error thats its not registerd.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

put this code in the end of `project/urls.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from allauth.socialaccount.models import SocialToken, SocialAccount, SocialApp

admin.site.unregister(SocialToken)
admin.site.unregister(SocialAccount)
admin.site.unregister(SocialApp)
```

Comment: How to unregister Email Address?

Comment: @ajinzrathod I think you should customize the User model.

Comment: Any source for the same?

Answer (score 0):

To unregister Accounts, it worked for me to use the following code. I placed it in the admin.py file of one of my apps.

```
from allauth.account.models import EmailAddress

admin.site.unregister(EmailAddress)
```